# Terminating a VM using IP address in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, virtual-machine

I want to know is there a way to terminate a VM in GCP through gcloud command using the static IP address instead of the instance name?

I am aware that a command exists for termination using the instance name.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

According to gcloud documentation this is NOT possible

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete

Instance name considered as unique identifier. IP address can be changed or unassigned, so you cannot rely on it to change or delete your instance.

Comment: but one can create a static IP address, which doesn't change. I am working with static IP address. But I have also come to the conclusion that it is not possible to shutdown a VM using IP address